# How can I draw a pretty population pyramid graph with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to plot a graph population pyramid.

I wrote this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
age,man,woman
+100 years,0,4
95 - 99 years,3,6
90 - 94 years,10,16
85 - 89 years,43,57
80 - 84 years,103,111
75 - 79 years,175,224
70 - 74 years,274,322
65 - 69 years,421,427
60 - 64 years,514,524
55 - 59 years,578,606
50 - 54 years,732,785
45 - 49 years,885,911
40 - 44 years,1044,1120
35 - 39 years,1192,1289
30 - 34 years,1315,1306
25 - 29 years,1214,1362
20 - 24 years,1360,1336
15 - 19 years,1471,1406
10 - 14 years,1495,1446
5 - 9 years,1375,1351
0 - 4 years,1325,1257
}\loadedtable


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width =\textwidth,
    height = 0.6*\textheight,
    enlarge x limits=0.6,
    xbar = 0pt,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    y dir = reverse,
    nodes near coords,
    bar width=8pt,
    bar shift=0pt,
    axis x line= left,
    nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize, color=black},
    xticklabel= {\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
    symbolic y coords={+100 years,95 - 99 years,90 - 94 years,85 - 89 years,80 - 84 years,75 - 79 years,70 - 74 years,65 - 69 years,60 - 64 years,55 - 59 years,50 - 54 years,45 - 49 years,40 - 44 years,35 - 39 years,30 - 34 years,25 - 29 years,20 - 24 years,15 - 19 years,10 - 14 years,5 - 9 years,0 - 4 years},
   ytick={+100 years,95 - 99 years,90 - 94 years,85 - 89 years,80 - 84 years,75 - 79 years,70 - 74 years,65 - 69 years,60 - 64 years,55 - 59 years,50 - 54 years,45 - 49 years,40 - 44 years,35 - 39 years,30 - 34 years,25 - 29 years,20 - 24 years,15 - 19 years,10 - 14 years,5 - 9 years,0 - 4 years}
            ]
        \addplot [fill = cyan!50]    table[y=age,x expr={-\thisrow{man}/31395*100}] \loadedtable;%31395 is the total population
        \addlegendentry{Man}
        \addplot [fill = magenta!50] table[y=age,x expr={\thisrow{woman}/31395*100}] \loadedtable;%31395 is the total population
        \addlegendentry{Woman}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the result is an ugly graph:

[image]

How can I improve it to obtain something like this?

[image]

Comment: It might be easier in this case to use straight Tikz instead of pgfplots.  Start by stacking and naming all the nodes of the far left.  Or perhaps the faint color bars.

Comment: Instead of a graph you could try with a `tabular` with `pgfplotstable` help.

Comment: I'am almost there!! = )

Comment: Waiting for answer!!!

Comment: @leonardocesar: Just out of interest: Which country is it?

Comment: @moose this data is from Mandaguari/PR - Brazil.
http://www.censo2010.ibge.gov.br/sinopse/webservice/frm_piramide.php?codigo=411420&corhomem=3d4590&cormulher=9cdbfc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It takes a lot of work to be pretty!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
age,man,woman
+100 years,0,4
95 - 99 years,3,6
90 - 94 years,10,16
85 - 89 years,43,57
80 - 84 years,103,111
75 - 79 years,175,224
70 - 74 years,274,322
65 - 69 years,421,427
60 - 64 years,514,524
55 - 59 years,578,606
50 - 54 years,732,785
45 - 49 years,885,911
40 - 44 years,1044,1120
35 - 39 years,1192,1289
30 - 34 years,1315,1306
25 - 29 years,1214,1362
20 - 24 years,1360,1336
15 - 19 years,1471,1406
10 - 14 years,1495,1446
5 - 9 years,1375,1351
0 - 4 years,1325,1257
}\loadedtable

\newlength{\dy}\setlength{\dy}{\baselineskip}
\newlength{\dx}\setlength{\dx}{0.007em}
\newlength{\temp}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\edef\rows{\pgfmathresult}
% compute total for percentages
\setlength{\temp}{0pt}
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,\rows}{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\y}{man}\of\loadedtable
  \global\advance\temp by \pgfplotsretval pt
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\y}{woman}\of\loadedtable
  \global\advance\temp by \pgfplotsretval pt
}
\pgfmathparse{0.01\temp}
\edef\total{\pgfmathresult}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,2\dy) {Population Pyramid - 2010};
\node[below,text=Navy] at (-8em,0) {\huge\mars};
\node[below,text=HotPink] at (8em,0) {\huge\venus};

\foreach \y in {0,1,...,\rows}{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\y}{age}\of\loadedtable
  \node[left] at (-19em,-\y\dy) {\strut\pgfplotsretval};
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\y}{man}\of\loadedtable
  \node[left] at (-15em,-\y\dy) {\strut\pgfplotsretval};
  \node[left,fill=Navy,text width=\pgfplotsretval\dx,text height=.8\dy,inner sep=0]
    at (0,-\y\dy+0.1\dy) {};
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval/\total}
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\per}
  \node[left] at (-\pgfplotsretval\dx,-\y\dy) {\small\strut\per\%};
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\y}{woman}\of\loadedtable
  \node[left] at (17em,-\y\dy) {\strut\pgfplotsretval};
  \node[right,fill=HotPink,text width=\pgfplotsretval\dx,text height=.8\dy,inner sep=0]
    at (0,-\y\dy+0.1\dy) {};
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval/\total}
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}{\per}
  \node[right] at (\pgfplotsretval\dx,-\y\dy) {\small\strut\per\%};
}
\node[left] at (-3em,-\rows\dy-.9\dy) {Man};
\node[left,fill=Navy,text width=2em,text height=.8\dy,inner sep=0]
  at (-1mm,-\rows\dy-.9\dy) {};
\node[right,fill=HotPink,text width=2em,text height=.8\dy,inner sep=0]
  at (+1mm,-\rows\dy-.9\dy) {};
\node[right] at (3em,-\rows\dy-.9\dy) {Woman};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pyramid]

You can adjust the size by adjusting the font, or with more precision using \resizebox.

Comment: I should mention that I stole the symbols from leonardo cesar's solution.

Comment: wow! amazing solution!!! but there is a little problem with logic! you must to divide each group age by total population. thanks!!!

Comment: Okay, change made.

Comment: This solution is nice, but the age ranges use a hyphen with spaces, which is typographically poor. Correct would be an en dash without spaces.

Comment: @lblb Correct. A simple workaround is to write `95--99 years` etc in the data table itself.

Answer (score 12):

this look better = )

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=true]{
age,man,woman
+100 years,0,4
95 - 99 years,3,6
90 - 94 years,10,16
85 - 89 years,43,57
80 - 84 years,103,111
75 - 79 years,175,224
70 - 74 years,274,322
65 - 69 years,421,427
60 - 64 years,514,524
55 - 59 years,578,606
50 - 54 years,732,785
45 - 49 years,885,911
40 - 44 years,1044,1120
35 - 39 years,1192,1289
30 - 34 years,1315,1306
25 - 29 years,1214,1362
20 - 24 years,1360,1336
15 - 19 years,1471,1406
10 - 14 years,1495,1446
5 - 9 years,1375,1351
0 - 4 years,1325,1257
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=popaxis,
    scale only axis,
    xbar,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=5,
    %xbar=2pt,
    %xlabel={\%},
    width=0.5*\textwidth, height= 0.5*\textheight,
   y dir = reverse,
   nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
   every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize, color=black},
   xticklabel= {\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
    y tick label style={text width=3cm,align=center},
    axis x line=left,
    axis y line=none,
%
    enlarge x limits = {value=0.15,upper},
    axis line style={-},
    clip=false
]
\addplot[magenta,fill=magenta!50] table[y expr =\coordindex, x expr={\thisrow{woman}/31395*100}] \loadedtable;%total pop = 31395 
%
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lastrow}{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
\node[xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,\lastrow) {\textcolor{cyan}{\huge\mars} Man}; 
\node[xshift= 1.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,\lastrow) {\textcolor{magenta}{\huge\venus} Woman}; 
\node[xshift= 0.0cm,yshift=-2.0cm,align=center] at (axis cs:0,\lastrow) {\%}; 
%
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ 
at={(popaxis.north west)},anchor=north east, %xshift=-3cm,
scale only axis,
    xbar = 0,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 5,
    width=0.5*\textwidth,
    height= 0.5*\textheight,
    x dir=reverse,
    y dir=reverse,
    nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate = 0, anchor = east, font=\scriptsize, color=black},
    xticklabel= {\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
    axis x line=left,
    axis y line*=left,
%
    ytick = data,
    yticklabels from table = {\loadedtable}{age},
    ytick align=center,
    ytick pos=left,
    enlarge x limits = {value=0.15,upper},
    axis line style={-}
]
\addplot[cyan,fill=cyan!50] table[y expr =\coordindex, x expr={\thisrow{man}/31395*100}] \loadedtable; %total pop = 31395 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: prettier]

Comment: This solution is nice, but the age ranges use a hyphen with spaces, which is typographically poor. Correct would be an en dash without spaces